# Azure Active Directory B2C Pricing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to calculate AAD B2C Pricing and it has a section called, Authentication which is based on generation of Token. I wanted to know which of the below operation I need consider for Authentications. I think all has to be considered for Pricing. I am using Open ID Connect for Authentication and OAuth 2.0 for further Authorization (with Access and Refresh Token)

1. Getting ID Token after Authentication
2. Getting Refresh Token
3. Getting Access Token
4. If we have logic to get Access Token before it expires, then generation of Access Token using Refresh Token
5. When Front end calls API, API Validates the token

So can someone help me if I need to consider all above cases while calculating my pricing. For example, For very Login and say the Access Token expires every 5 mins (needs 4 refresh for my 20 mins session), I would need minimum of 
Id Token Generation +  Refresh Token + 4 times Access Token Generation. So this will take me to 6 Authentications? Also this way of Pricing will be very expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID and access tokens are issued in response to a single request to sign users in, then you'll be charged once for the initial response (#1 and #3) to the sign-in request and then charged once again for *each* subsequent response (*n* x #4) using the refresh token.

Comment: BTW, you have managing the fine balance between cost and security, where security (i.e. the shortest-possible lifetime for the access tokens) is costly. :)

Comment: Thanks Chris! What about the point number 5, lets say I use the Azure API Management and validate these token with Validate JWT policy, I hope since this is a validation , I guess there should be no charges.

Comment: Usually for Finance World, having Access Token lifetime > 5 Mins is not Idea! But having such an option would increase the cost multi fold!

Comment: Hi @Manu RE #5: You aren't charged for a token validation. In fact, Azure AD B2C can't validate tokens, which are issued by it. It is responsibility of an API application, or the API Management service in your particular case, to download the Azure AD B2C metadata and validate tokens based on this published metadata.